# How to fix messed up characters on rs232 customer display

Tags: php, angularjs, serial-port

I'm trying to integrate a customer display to my angularjs, php billing system. I'm using a Partner SP-550 with it's CD7220 VFD 2x20 customer display. When i try to display strings with powershell it works perfect. But when i send a string using php serial some characters are messed up. I think it's showing some different characters. What could be the reason for this issue? And how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this brochure, the character code that can be used will be ASCII range (0x20-0x7F).
[CD-7220 CUSTOMER DISPLAY](https://www.partnertechcorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/PTU-CD-7220-050317.pdf)

```
Character Type  96 alphanumeric  
             13 international character sets including US, French, Germany, Spanish, etc.
```

Then, it seems that some characters are switched as international character set by hardware setting.
Ask the vendor whether there are tools such as tools to change the international character set.

Probably this will have its own control escape sequence.
Please request vendor for programmer's guide and create display data accordingly.